# Java RESTful webservice-POST with payload

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

The input I have are a URL and a request payload.

Say,
URL: `https://somesresource.com`
Payload: {userId: "4566"}

The output I get back is a Json with several key-value pairs.

I tried doing this in Rest Console and the output(Json) looked good. But, when I try to run the following program the output is not the json but the file(html i suppose) from the URL's server. How do I retrieve the Json instead of the file?

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    String consumer() throws Exception {

        String line;
        String userId = "12345";
        StringBuffer jsonString = new StringBuffer();
        URL url = new URL("https://somewebsite/userprofile");
        String payload="{\"userId\":\""+sid+"\"}";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            writer.write(payload);
            writer.close();
            System.out.print(connection.getInputStream().toString());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonString.append(line);
            }
            br.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
        return jsonString.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a converter in your application. I use RestFul Web service with Spring and use MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter for to & fro conversion of JSON. Please provide more details of your configuration if you are looking for a specific answer.